# Sublime Text: Find-and-replace within selection

Tags: sublime-text-2

Does Sublime Text 2 allow the user to perform find-and-replace, limited to the current selection?

I should think it must, only I've been unable after multiple searches to find how to carry it out.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is a button for that in ST2.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: True, there is a button. But how do you use it? In particular, how do you set "the selection"? From my experience ST2 uses the selection from the time when you opened the search bar. So if the bar is open already you have to close it first (Esc), then select the range of text you want to examine and then open it again (Ctrl+F or Ctrl+H). Pro tip: If the selection spans multiple lines it won't replace your current search expression.

Comment: Cmd+Opt+F on mac to open the find & replace console.

Comment: I'm completely puzzled as to why there is no keyboard shortcut for that "In selection", espacially since there is for all other options!  Do I really have to move my hand to the mouse to enable that? Seems to go against all ST stands for... (I'm using ST3)

Comment: @TheStoryCoder yeah it's dumb that that's no keyboard shortcut, but it turned out to be easy to make one, except the name of the command wasn't documented but I got lucky and guessed right. Here's the code to add to your user keybindings:  { "keys": ["alt+y"], "command": "toggle_in_selection", "context":
  [
   { "key": "setting.is_widget", "operator": "equal", "operand": true }
  ]
 },

Comment: A note for other people who were confused like me: when you select several lines of text, then press Ctrl+H (which opens Find & Replace) and start typing in the "Find what" field, the selected lines stop looking selected, but *they still are*. If it wasn't for that problem, I wouldn't have even searched for a solution and found this post. BTW I seem to remember that problem wasn't there before, so maybe after a reboot or something it'll disappear.

Answer (score 8):

Here's what you need to add to your user keybindings:

```
{ "keys": ["alt+y"], "command": "toggle_in_selection", "context":
    [
        { "key": "setting.is_widget", "operator": "equal", "operand": true }
    ]
},
```

Yeah, it's dumb that that's no default keybinding set.

Also the command name "`toggle_in_selection`" wasn't documented, but I guessed and got lucky.

---

EDIT TO ADD:

```
/*
btw, the way i want to use find by default
(actually, i use replace by default, but same dif),
is for "in_selection" to be true by default,
*unless* the selection is empty.
(
the default is that "in_selection" is *false* by default,
unless the selection contains a newline.
)
i finally got around to digging up how to get that,
which is apparently by changing the *keybindings* you use to pop open the find(/replace) panel?
*/
    { "keys": ["ctrl+f"], "command": "show_panel", "args": {"panel": "replace", "in_selection": true}},
    { "keys": ["ctrl+f"], "command": "show_panel", "args": {"panel": "replace", "in_selection": false},
    "context":
        [
            { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true}
        ]
    },
```

Comment: The keybinding already exists by default.

Comment: Huh. Wonder why I was missing it, then... the only "toggle_" things I had in my default bindings were: `toggle_side_bar toggle_full_screen toggle_distraction_free toggle_overwrite toggle_record_macro toggle_setting toggle_comment toggle_case_sensitive toggle_regex toggle_whole_word toggle_preserve_case`

Answer (score 7):

If your selection includes a line break, the "within selection" button will be automatically activated - on ST2

The smart activation has been lost on ST3, unfortunately. You can follow up on that here http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=11679

Comment: It's now possible to bring back this functionality by using: "auto_find_in_selection": true

Comment: How do I invoke it automatically when it doesn't include a line break? For examples when you have a really long line that spans many "rows"? Everytime I have that line selected and invoke search, it disables the "in selection" option.

Answer (score 3):

Just select the text you want to search, then click Replace from the find menu. It will automatically do it within your selection.

Answer (score 3):

(with Mac OS X specific shortcuts) to replace `some name` with `new name`:

1. place the cursor above the text
2. Find `some name`: <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>, type `some name` (sometimes need to press <kbd>return</kbd>)
3. Specify replace: <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>r</kbd>, <kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> to get to replace field, type `new name`, ***don't*** press <kbd>return</kbd>
4. repeat <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> until done.

Comment: Does anyone know a faster way of doing this?!  It's pretty ridiculous and unnecessarily hard to remember

Comment: see @oliver-g 's answer - ST2 does so by default, and if you have disabled it, just click `ctrl+H` and left to "Find What:" there's a button titeled "In selection"

Answer (score 2):

cmd+option+F on mac will give you find and replace window

Comment: OK, but when the user clicks “Replace All”, will it replace (1) all occurrences in the file, (2) all occurrences from the current position to the end of the file, or (3) all occurrences ***within the current selection?*** … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 1):

*I'm adding another answer as the best and most helpful solution (in my opinion) was hidden in a comment and I almost missed it (thanks @mdrozdziel).*

Select the text you want to search within, hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to bring up the find and replace toolbar. There is a [button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zG9uB.png) to the right of the bank of buttons on the left which will activate search within selection.

This is off by default in ST3 but you can set it to default on when you select more than one line by adding `"auto_find_in_selection": true` to your preference file (found by inputting <kbd>Alt</kbd>,<kbd>N</kbd>,<kbd>S</kbd>,<kbd>Enter</kbd>).

Answer (score 1):

Mac:

- Find:       <kbd>⌘ CMD</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Replace: <kbd>⌘ CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

Ubuntu/Window:

- Find:       <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Replace: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

the key to work with replace within selection is to **FIRST select the text** then go to **find > replace** then fill in text for what your are gonna find & replace, then **check the button tooltipped "in selection"** then click on "Replace All"...